# In parallel CPU architecture, how do CPU's in a distributed memory architecture communicate with each other?

Tags: memory, parallel-processing, architecture, cpu, distributed

When we are talking about the shared memory CPU architecture, if the CPU's want to communicate with each other, then they have to look for a "variable" that they share - inside the shared memory. But what if we have distributed memory instead? How do the CPU's communicate with each other, if at all?

PS - The type of processing here is parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : *"How do the CPU's <sub>( In parallel CPU architecture )</sub> communicate with each other, if at all?"*

Let me take one such smart example - an Epiphany<sup>TM</sup> architecture, designed by Andreas Olofsson and his Adapteva team.

[image]

These smart many-core parallel RISC CPU use both the NoC-hardware implemented 2D-mesh networks for intra-system, inter-node hardware interactions (named **`eMesh`**<sup>TM</sup>), consisting of triple-layered, specialised, networks `[ cMesh | xMesh | rMesh ]`, and have an extended reach of using inter-system eLINK<sup>TM</sup> network to communicate with other, non-local systems.

This shows, how smart parallel architectures can promote the state-of-art solutions. Great respect to Andreas Olofsson and his team.

Just for the context - this came some fourty years **after** the pioneers from InMOS (UK, Bristol) first launched a Transputer architecture with (guess what, similar) parallel-networks equipped with adding also a tight-most knit parallel-language **`occam`**, that helped generate principally hard parallel software right-fit onto the Transputer in-silicon properties and yet was IMHO up until these years the most ***productive*** parallel-systems language with support for Real-Time System controls, to design such smart & demanding parallel-control systems, as the ESA Giotto satellite and many others.

PS :
A cool lesson on how to do **`[PARALLEL]`**-computing right right from the in-silicon level, wasn't it? - all respect goes to InMOS / occam people.